# Create a table in compact framework

Tags: c#, datagrid, compact-framework

I need to display some data into a table but i don't get wich class/object to do so in compact framework.
The table doesn't have to do anything, just display the data.
I have tried with datagrid like this:

```
DataGrid table = new DataGrid();
table.Location = new Point(13,190);
table.Size =  new Size(221,100);
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(5);
list.Add(7);
list.Add(9);
table.DataSource = list;
this.Controls.Add(table);
```

But this produce what seems to be an empty datagrid(one column, four rows and one row have an arrow).

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get "empty" grid is:

[To bind the DataGrid to a strongly typed array of objects, the object type must contain public properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.datasource%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

You use `int` as list type parameter, but `int` has no properies to display.
Replace list type parameter with other type with public properties and you get what you want.

Here, try this:

```
   DataGrid table = new DataGrid();
   table.Location = new Point(0, 0);
   table.Size = new Size(221, 100);
   List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<object, object>>();
   list.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("asdfasdf", 3685745));
   list.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("sdfgsdfgsd", 54));
   list.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("xcvbxcvbxcvb", 341234));
   list.Add(new KeyValuePair<object, object>("56785678567", 56));
   table.DataSource = list;
   this.Controls.Add(table);
```

If you need to display data like ints or strings, you can use linq do this:

```
table.DataSource = list.Select(item=>new {item}).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, but whay to i get the empty datagrid even with this?

   `public struct Data
    {
    public string val1;
    public string val2;
    }
    DataGrid table = new DataGrid();
    table.Location = new Point(13,190);
    table.Size = new Size(221, 100);
    List<Data> list = new List<Data>();
    Data stuff = new Data();
    stuff.val1 = "3";
    stuff.val2 = "A";
    list.Add(stuff);
    table.DataSource = list;
    this.Controls.Add(table);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `List<int>`, try using a List of Objects, where the Object is a class you write to store your data.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyData {

  public MyData() {
    Date = DateTime.MinValue;
  }

  public int ID { get; set; }

  public string Text { get; set; }

  public DateTime Date { get; set; }

  public override ToString() {
    return string.Format("{0}: {1}", ID, Text);
  }

}
```

Now, use the `MyData` class to create your list and fill it with ...whatever you have:

```
var list = new List<MyData>();
list.Add(new MyData() { ID = 5, Text = "5", new DateTime(2012, 5, 1) });
list.Add(new MyData() { ID = 7, Text = "7", new DateTime(2012, 7, 1) });
list.Add(new MyData() { ID = 9, Text = "9", new DateTime(2012, 9, 1) });
table.DataSource = list;
```

And, FYI: the word `table` is not a good choice for a **DataGrid** instance. People on here will not know what you're talking about.